# Meaning of simple sentence in different tenses

Tags: grammar, tenses, context

Hello I would like you to explain me the discrepancies and the nuances of using this simple sentence in different tenses. I would like to know the context when each of this should be used this will clarify me english language as the all!

- **I play football.**    | I belong to football team professional or amateur
- **I am playing football.** | When in the middle of playing
- **I have been playing football.** | When I come back to home to drink water and my grandpa says what are you doing you are so sweaty, and I will soon go back.
- **I have played football.** | Today morning played football, Played at least one in all the lifetime
- **I was playing football,yesterday.** | Start elaborating about yesterday match I played
- **I played football, yesterday.** | Just say I have played without elaborating or more details.
- **I had played football, before she arrived.**  | before other past event.
- **I had been playing football, before she arrived.** | before other past event but somehow underlining duration of playing.
- **I am used to playing football.**  | I am accustomed to playing football, I have this in blood.
- **I used to play football,** | but now I'm not interested in this? not have been playing for years
- **I will play football.** | I am getting ball and say grandpa that I am going out now
- **I will be playing football.** | planning that tonight will be match
- **I will have been playing football tomorrow.** | when I am telling grandpa that when she will be tonight at school to pick me up I will have been playing football (just than finish it)
- **I am going to play football on Sunday.** | plan to play football like in Calendar

You can write some context to this sentences when it will show typical usage and help me to understand situation in which cases what tense should I use. Thx for any help.

UPDATE
Ok I have added description of context in which I will use each of the tense. Just say me I am correct or not with this.

Comment: Even as you are reading this comment, an entire army of grammarians and lexicographers are busy organising themselves to decide who shall analyse each of your carefully selected sentences.

Comment: We have an excellent question about tenses in English: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another

Comment: ok i have added context to narrow the question to true/false or potential hints

Comment: I'm sorry, @MichałZiobro, your enhancements are not anywhere near proper English, either grammatically or even in word choice.  It looks a bit like you're translating something literally from another language but it's not really acceptable English.  Have you visited our sister site, English for Learners?  I'm going to recommend that this question is migrated there. http://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the OP was editing his post, I put some additional context to illustrate the usage of these expressions:

- I play football (I have my sport licence)
- I am playing football (and I will be tired at the end of the game).
- I have been playing football or (during 2 years, when I was a student)
- I have played football (once, when I was a student).
- I was playing football,yesterday (and I got a calf muscle injury).
- I played football, yesterday (and I will play again tomorrow).
- I had played football, before she arrived (Once or twice, before her arrival).
- I had been playing football, before she arrive**d**(regularly before her arrival).
- I am used to playing football (*incorrect*).
- I used to play football,(but now I'm no more interested)
- I will play football (I don't play football at  the moment, but after my return to Manchester, I will).
- I will be playing football (next Sunday morning).
- I will have been playing football tomorrow (*incorrect*).
- I am going to play football on Sunday (It has been decided yesterday).

Comment: thx for clarifying :) It will help a lot.